# Airflow BashOperator completes code with error code 0. However, Airflow marks the task as failed

Tags: airflow

I am working on [Airflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Airflow). I have several Bash operators which calls the Python code. Normally it works fine. However, from yesterday I faced a situation, I cannot understand. In the logs of the task, everything is ok as seen in the below;

```
*** Reading local file: /opt/airflow/logs/dag_id=derin_emto_preprocess/run_id=manual__2022-10-01T13:54:50.246801+00:00/task_id=emto_preprocess-month0day0/attempt=1.log
[2022-10-01, 13:55:21 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1159} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: derin_emto_preprocess.emto_preprocess-month0day0 manual__2022-10-01T13:54:50.246801+00:00 [queued]>
[2022-10-01, 13:55:21 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1159} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: derin_emto_preprocess.emto_preprocess-month0day0 manual__2022-10-01T13:54:50.246801+00:00 [queued]>
[2022-10-01, 13:55:21 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1356} INFO -
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2022-10-01, 13:55:21 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1357} INFO - Starting attempt 1 of 1
[2022-10-01, 13:55:21 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1358} INFO -
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2022-10-01, 13:55:21 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1377} INFO - Executing <Task(BashOperator): emto_preprocess-month0day0> on 2022-10-01 13:54:50.246801+00:00
[2022-10-01, 13:55:21 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:52} INFO - Started process 624 to run task
[2022-10-01, 13:55:21 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:79} INFO - Running: ['***', 'tasks', 'run', 'derin_emto_preprocess', 'emto_preprocess-month0day0', 'manual__2022-10-01T13:54:50.246801+00:00', '--job-id', '8958', '--raw', '--subdir', 'DAGS_FOLDER/derin_emto_preprocess.py', '--cfg-path', '/tmp/tmpjn_8tmiv', '--error-file', '/tmp/tmp_jr_2w3j']
[2022-10-01, 13:55:21 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:80} INFO - Job 8958: Subtask emto_preprocess-month0day0
[2022-10-01, 13:55:21 UTC] {task_command.py:369} INFO - Running <TaskInstance: derin_emto_preprocess.emto_preprocess-month0day0 manual__2022-10-01T13:54:50.246801+00:00 [running]> on host 5b44f8453a08
[2022-10-01, 13:55:21 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1571} INFO - Exporting the following env vars:
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_OWNER=***
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_ID=derin_emto_preprocess
AIRFLOW_CTX_TASK_ID=emto_preprocess-month0day0
AIRFLOW_CTX_EXECUTION_DATE=2022-10-01T13:54:50.246801+00:00
AIRFLOW_CTX_TRY_NUMBER=1
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_RUN_ID=manual__2022-10-01T13:54:50.246801+00:00
[2022-10-01, 13:55:21 UTC] {subprocess.py:62} INFO - Tmp dir root location:
 /tmp
[2022-10-01, 13:55:21 UTC] {subprocess.py:74} INFO - Running command: ['bash', '-c', 'python /opt/***/dags/scripts/derin/pipeline/pipeline.py --valid_from=20200101 --valid_until=20200102 --purpose=emto_preprocess --module=emto_preprocess --***=True']
[2022-10-01, 13:55:21 UTC] {subprocess.py:85} INFO - Output:
[2022-10-01, 13:55:24 UTC] {subprocess.py:92} INFO - 2022-10-01 13:55:22 :  Hello, world!
[2022-10-01, 13:55:24 UTC] {subprocess.py:92} INFO - 2022-10-01 13:55:22 :  [20200101, 20200102)
[2022-10-01, 13:55:24 UTC] {subprocess.py:92} INFO - 2022-10-01 13:55:22 :  Running emto_preprocess purpose
[2022-10-01, 13:55:24 UTC] {subprocess.py:92} INFO - Current directory : /opt/***/dags
[2022-10-01, 13:55:24 UTC] {subprocess.py:92} INFO - 2022-10-01 13:55:22 :  Airflow parameter passed: changing configuration..
[2022-10-01, 13:55:24 UTC] {subprocess.py:92} INFO - 2022-10-01 13:55:24 :  Parallel threads: 15
[2022-10-01, 13:55:24 UTC] {subprocess.py:92} INFO - 2022-10-01 13:55:24 :  External money transfer out: preprocess is starting..
[2022-10-01, 13:55:24 UTC] {subprocess.py:92} INFO -
Thread None for emto_preprocess:   0%|          | 0/1 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
Thread None for emto_preprocess: 100%|██████████| 1/1 [00:00<00:00, 12633.45it/s]
[2022-10-01, 13:55:24 UTC] {subprocess.py:92} INFO - 2022-10-01 13:55:24 :  DEBUG: Checking existing files
[2022-10-01, 13:55:24 UTC] {subprocess.py:92} INFO - 2022-10-01 13:55:24 :  This module is already processed
[2022-10-01, 13:55:24 UTC] {subprocess.py:92} INFO - 2022-10-01 13:55:24 :  Good bye!
[2022-10-01, 13:55:24 UTC] {subprocess.py:96} INFO - Command exited with return code 0
[2022-10-01, 13:55:24 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1400} INFO - Marking task as SUCCESS. dag_id=derin_emto_preprocess, task_id=emto_preprocess-month0day0, execution_date=20221001T135450, start_date=20221001T135521, end_date=20221001T135524
[2022-10-01, 13:55:24 UTC] {local_task_job.py:156} INFO - Task exited with return code 0
[2022-10-01, 13:55:25 UTC] {local_task_job.py:273} INFO - 0 downstream tasks scheduled from follow-on schedule check
```

However, Airflow marked this task as failed. How can I fix this?

Comment: In what context? Where does it run? Under what conditions? Versions of Airflow, Python, Bash, operating system, etc. How is the Python code actually called?

Comment: As @PeterMortensen mentions, we need a bit more to go on to figure out what's going on. Based on the logs, everything looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

I understood and solved this weird problem. When Airflow renders/upload the dags, it reads all files in /airflow/dags/ folder. I have a data storage folder under this with 250 GB consisting of many feather file. I guess reading files take too much time, and creates this kind of situation. Solution is creating an .airflowignore file, and adding other directories (not storing dag files) in .airflowignore file.